# HelloFacebookSample onBackpressed gives status success message even not post status

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated sdk in my application but when i am going to sharedialog and press back button sdk gives "success" even not post click.

For more details SDK v 3.5 and it's code which given success while i am trying to test using real Facebook account and pressing cancel.but while using test account and when i check with this "getNativeDialogCompletionGesture" method it's working but not in real account.

My requirement is while pressing cancel it should not show success on backpressed.

```
public static boolean handleActivityResult(Context context, PendingCall appCall, int requestCode, Intent data,
        Callback callback) {
    if (requestCode != appCall.getRequestCode()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (attachmentStore != null) {
        attachmentStore.cleanupAttachmentsForCall(context, appCall.getCallId());
    }

    if (callback != null) {
        if (NativeProtocol.isErrorResult(data)) {
            Exception error = NativeProtocol.getErrorFromResult(data);
            callback.onError(appCall, error, data.getExtras());
        } else {
            callback.onComplete(appCall, data.getExtras());
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```